# Relay access denied when forwarding email via domain registrar

Tags: email, gmail, forwarding, domain-name, relay

UPDATE: It turns out that it took several hours for my changes to take effect. So everything's fine now. But I hope this question and answer will be useful for someone.

I have a domain name which I've owned for a couple of years, but haven't previously used for anything. I'm now trying to set up an email address under this domain name: specifically, I've set up email forwarding with my domain registrar (porkbun.com) which points to my real email account on GMail.

I have tried to send several test messages to the new address (from a separate GMail account), but they are all rejected with the following error message:

```
The response from the remote server was:
554 5.7.1 <user@domain.info>: Relay access denied
```

[of course, the actual error message contains the actual email address]

Now, I have two other domains registered with Porkbun, and have previously had several other domains registered with Porkbun and other registrars, and have successfully used email forwarding with all of them. I have not done anything unique with the configuration of the problem domain.

Anyway, it seems to me that the first step in troubleshooting is to find *where* the error is occurring. I have opened the raw text of the bounced messages and found that there is no reference to "porkbun.com". Based on that, I am *guessing* that the messages are being rejected by Porkbun ... but I don't have a deep understanding of how email works.

So, what next? (other than contacting Porkbun support, which will have to wait until tomorrow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your domain's MX records are pointing to mail servers that aren't configured to accept mail for that domain. ("Relay access denied" means the server does not recognize the envelope-'To' domain as neither incoming *nor* outgoing, and is assuming that you're trying to bounce off it as a third party.)

1. First, verify that the domain is delegated to **the correct nameservers** which store your DNS records. (You're probably using the ones [provided by your registrar](https://kb.porkbun.com/article/63-how-to-switch-to-porkbuns-nameservers), Porkbun.) One tool for doing so is `dnstracer`:

   ```
   > dnstracer -s. yahoo.com

   Tracing to yahoo.com[a] via A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET, maximum of 3 retries
   A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET [.] (2001:0503:ba3e:0000:0000:0000:0002:0030) 
   |\___ d.gtld-servers.net [com] (2001:0500:856e:0000:0000:0000:0000:0030) 
   |     |\___ ns4.yahoo.com [yahoo.com] (98.138.11.157) Got authoritative answer
   ```

   If you don't have dnstracer, try [this online version](https://simpledns.plus/lookup-dg). (Unfortunately, the online version of *actual* dnstracer seems to be down now, but this one seems to do the job well enough. You are looking for the "Received referral response" part here – the "authoritative response" part is secondary.)

   Doing this manually with an `*.info` domain:

   1. Find the nameservers for `info`:

      ```
      > nslookup -q=ns info

      info name server b2.info.afilias-nst.org.
      ```
   2. Ask those nameservers about your domain:

      ```
      > nslookup -q=ns example.info b2.info.afilias-nst.org

      example.info name server curitiba.ns.porkbun.com
      ```

   Porkbun has [instructions](https://kb.porkbun.com/article/63-how-to-switch-to-porkbuns-nameservers) for switching nameservers, as well as a list of the correct nameservers for use with their provided DNS control panel.
2. Then, use `host -t mx ...` or `nslookup -q=mx ...` to look up **the MX records** of your domain and verify that the domain is pointing to the correct *mail* servers.

   ```
   > nslookup -q=mx yahoo.com

   yahoo.com mail is handled by 1 mta7.am0.yahoodns.net.
   ```

   It's worth also making a direct check against your domain's nameservers from step 2.2 (instead of going through the usual resolvers you use):

   ```
   > nslooukp -q=mx example.info curitiba.ns.porkbun.com
   ```

   Porkbun has a list of [expected MX records](https://kb.porkbun.com/article/47-how-to-use-porkbun-email-when-your-dns-is-hosted-elsewhere) for their "email forwarding" service.
3. If the MX records are pointing to the correct SMTP servers, call technical support of whoever runs those mailservers.

Comment: Just a quick heads up: Propagation of DNS updates is fast these days, but it still can take some time. So, if you just updated your DNS records, wait at least a few minutes, if not an hour.